# Need help initializing/calling methods

Tags: java, methods

For a beginning class for coding in Java SE (using NetBeans 8.1 IDE). What I am trying to do is this

Main file immediately initializes and goes to playDice, which checks the players current balance, asks for a bet amount, and if the current balance is greater than 0, and the bet amount is less than or equal to the current balance, it initializes the method  `public static int determineWinnings(.....)` . This right here is my problem. This is my current code for trying to get the program to initialize determineWinnings.

```
if (balance >= 0 && balance >= betAmmount) {
    determineWinnings();
}
```

With that code, I get an error message saying  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK3qW.png) . What is the fix?

Full code, if needed, for a reference

```
package dicegame;

import static dicegame.UserInput.*;

public class DiceGame {

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Lets play the dice game!");

    System.out.println("Loading");
    playDice();
    }


public static void playDice(){
    System.out.println("Hello, please input the ammount you will like to bet!");
    int balance=1000;
    int betAmmount=getInt();

    if(balance>=0 && balance>=betAmmount){
        determineWinnings();
    }
    else if(balance<=betAmmount){
        System.out.println("You can not bet in this game! Your bet can not be greater than your current balance!");
    }
    else if(balance==0){
        System.out.println("You can not bet in this game! You have no money left!");
    }        
}         


public static int determineWinnings(int balance, int betAmmount){
    int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;

    System.out.println("Rolling...");
    System.out.println("You rolled a " + die1);
    System.out.println("You rolled a " + die2);


    if(die1==die2){
        if(die1==1 && die2==1){
            System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU HIT THE JACKPOT! Your current balance will be multiplied by 12!");
            balance=balance*12;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is" + balance);
        }
        else if(die1==2 && die2==2){
            System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! You won! Your current balance will be doubled!");
            balance=balance*12;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is" + balance);
        }                        
        else if(die1==3 && die2==3){
            System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! You won! Your current balance will be tripled!");
            balance=balance*12;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is" + balance);
        }
        else if(die1==4 && die2==4){
            System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU HIT THE JACKPOT! Your current balance will be quadrupled!");
            balance=balance*12;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is" + balance);
        } 
        else if(die1==5 && die2==5){
            System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU HIT THE JACKPOT! Your current balance will be quintupled!");
            balance=balance*12;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is" + balance);
        }
        else if(die1==6 && die2==6){
            System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU HIT THE JACKPOT! Your current balance will be sextupled!");
            balance=balance*12;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is" + balance);
        }
    }        
    else{
        balance=balance-betAmmount;
        System.out.println("You lost! Your new balance is" + balance);
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: look at what your `determineWinnings` method expects as parameters and how you are calling it (aka. read what the error says)

Comment: You declared `determineWinnings(int balance, int betAmmount)` so it *requires* two `int` values, but you are not passing any when you call it via `determineWinnings()`.

Comment: Your method expects two integers: `determineWinnings(int balance, int betAmmount)`  You're passing it no integers: `determineWinnings()`  You need to supply values to the method when you call it.  For example: `determineWinnings(balance, betAmount)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `balance` and `betAmount` to `determineWinnings(...)`:

```
if (balance >= 0 && balance >= betAmmount) {
    determineWinnings(balance, betAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared determineWinnings as

```
public static int determineWinnings(int balance, int betAmmount)
```

yet you are calling it without any arguments

```
determineWinnings()
```

You should be passing in two ints.